# Как сделать горизонтальный слайдер с вертикальными миниатюрами?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, есть макет в котором в блоке "Руководство" выводится по 4 человека, снизу есть стрелочки переключения, при клике на стрелочку вправо должны показываться следующие 4 человека. [image] Думал попробовать с owl-carousel, но как-то не получалось. 
Придумал три пути решения:
1) Как-то циклом сделать так чтобы каждые 4 статьи были обернуты в div блок с классом "slide" (но мне кажется это не реально)
2) Может есть какая-та функция в owl-carousel чтобы этих 4 человека отображались не горизонтально а вертикально
3) Подключить вообще другой скрипт который может реализовать такое

Comment: Была подобная задача, к тому же с owlcarousel, сделал так как в первом пункте. Что вы пробовали?

Comment: Я еще не пробовал так как не знаю как это реализовать)

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно получить список всех руководителей в массив и дальше просто обернуть их в див по 4-ро. Например так:

```
foreach( $managers as $key => $manager ) {
    if ( ! $key % 4 ) { ?>
        <div class="slide">
    <?php }
    //your block with manager
    if ( 3 === $key % 4 ) { ?>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
if ( count( $managers ) % 4 ) { ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Последний if на случай если в последнем слайде меньше 4-х руководителей.